# Copying children elements of one division to another along with all associated events

Tags: javascript, html, appendchild

I am trying to replace a certain div element `parent` with another one `newparent`. I want to copy only some of `parent`'s children and put them in `newparent`, and then replace the `parent` by `newparent`.
Here is a snippet of my code:

```
var sb_button = parent.firstChild;
    var temp;
    while(sb_button) {
        console.log("loop: ");
        console.log(sb_button.id);
        temp = sb_button;
        if(sb_button.id != curr_button.id && sb_button.id != prev_button.id) {
            console.log("if");
            newparent.appendChild(temp);
            }
        else if(sb_button.id == curr_button.id) {
            console.log("elseif");
            newparent.appendChild(temp);
            newparent.appendChild(prev_button);
            }
        else {
            console.log("else");
            }
        sb_button.parentNode = parent;
        console.log(sb_button.id)
        console.log(sb_button.parentNode.children);
        sb_button = sb_button.nextSibling;
        }
    parent.parentNode.replaceChild(newparent,parent);
```

EDIT :

So when I do  `newparent.appendChild(temp)` it modifies `sb_button`. What's the workaround for this?

Comment: So what goes wrong?  And what's logged with all that logging you've already inserted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't run your code, but there's a few weird things, perhaps one of which may cause the issue or help clear up the code so the issue is more obvious.

- the variable `temp` seems to be an alias for `sb_button`: you could remove the variable declaration and replace all references with `temp`
- `sb_button` is a confusing name for an arbitrary child node
- you're appending the node in `sb_button` to `newparent` within the if statement, but right after you're trying to set `sb_button_.parentNode` to `parent` - that's [not possible since `parentNode` is readonly](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1060184317) and it certainly doesn't make sense - you can't append the element to one element but have a different parent.
- are you trying to copy or move nodes?

**Edit:** given that you want to copy nodes, I believe you're looking for [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.cloneNode): make a copy of the node and append that copy, not the original node.

As a matter of clean design, when things get complicated, I'd avoid this kind of hard-to-reason-about while loop.  Instead, simply make an array of the nodes, order those the way you want (you could even do this using `sort` to make it immediately obvious you're just rearranging things), and then make a function that takes a `newparent` and the array and appends copies of all elements in array order to `newparent`.  Your example isn't that complex, but even here, I'd change the order of the if-clauses to have the "default" case in the final else.  e.g.:

```
for(var child = parent.firstChild; child; child = child.nextSibling) 
    if(child.id == curr_button.id) { //insert prev_button after curr_button
        newparent.appendChild(child.cloneNode(true));
        newparent.appendChild(prev_button.cloneNode(true));
    } else if(child.id != prev_button.id) {
        newparent.appendChild(child.cloneNode(true));
    }
parent.parentNode.replaceChild(newparent, parent);
```

The idea being to make it instantly obvious to the reader that all children are processed exactly once.

Comment: Suppose I have 4 siblings ordered in parent, I want to reorder the way siblings are arranged. ( suppose it's 1 2 3 4 in beginning, I want to do 1 3 2 4 based on the condition ) . 
I've corrected the third point you mentioned. 
. So how can I copy the exact behavior of `sb_button` to `temp` and now the modifications on `temp` should not affect `sb_button`?